# How to set different width for different form in mat-horizontal-stepper

Tags: css, sass, angular6, angular-material-6

I want to set different width for different form in mat-step.The content in first form to be as width of 400px and the second form content to be as width of 700px.

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="bottom" #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
       <div style="width:400px">
 <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>

       </div>

      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your address</ng-template>
      <div style="width:700px">
         <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Address" formControlName="secondCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      </div>


      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
    You are now done.
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

But it is not working , Can anyone please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: I am not sure. It should take the specified width. If you're talking about the form-field not taking the entire width, then you need to add `.mat-form-field { width: 100% }` to your css.

Answer (score 6):

Since only the visibility of the `mat-step components` are changing you should overwrite the width of the invisible ones.

Use the following code in the `CSS` file:

```
::ng-deep .mat-horizontal-stepper-content[aria-expanded="false"] {
  width: 0px !important;
}
```

After using this you can use different width sizes for every step.

Comment: Elegant solution to a most annoying problem. Thank you.